# How To Display Custom "Web Page Not Available" Error Page in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

pls help me to display custom Web Page Not Available error page...in webview..i tried many code and when i run the app it shows app has been stopped

Comment: can you share use the code that you are using to display webview

Comment: code is here - http://pastebin.com/zQCr8igB

Answer (score 1):

You can override onReceivedError  callback of [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) to achieve the desired functionality.

Either you can display some dialog to denot your custom  message or load the webview with any custom html available locally in your app.

Answer (score -1):

**USE this it working fine on my side. May be it will help you**

```
private WebView webviewSites;
 String URL="http://www.google.com";
    webviewSites = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_sites);
    WebSettings webSettings = webviewSites.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webviewSites.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webviewSites.loadUrl(URL);



public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                // mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Log.i("LOAD_URL", "" + url);

        }
```

Comment: This sample is making one of the most common mistakes. Please can you remove the call to loadUrl from shouldOverrideURLLoading so others don't copy this mistake. Thanks